# Cannot access data from a method in Vue.js (with Ionic)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework

I am trying to access a variable from a method, but I get :
`Property 'commentLikeVisible' does not exist on type '{ toggleCommentLikeVisible: () => void;`

Here is my code:

```
<template>
    <div 
        class="moments-item" 
        data-index="0"
    >
        <div class="item-right">
            <div class="item-ft">
                <div 
                    class="item-reply-btn" 
                    @click="toggleCommentLikeVisible"
                >
                    <span class="item-reply" />
                </div>
                <CommentLikeModal 
                    v-if="commentLikeVisible" 
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import CommentLikeModal from '@/components/CommentLikeModal.vue';

export default {
    name: 'MomentItem',
    components: {
        CommentLikeModal
    },
    data() {
        return {
            commentLikeVisible: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggleCommentLikeVisible: function() {
            this.commentLikeVisible = !this.commentLikeVisible;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I already tried `toggleCommentLikeVisible()` instead of
`toggleCommentLikeVisible: function()` with the same result.

I have no idea what could be wrong in there.

Comment: it should work, i simulate your code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-ts-forked-l6byg?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) and it works fine

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I know, I don't understand why it does not work, could it be something with ionic ? ( it worked for me too for a day or so and then I started getting the error message with no reason ! )

Comment: Could be some nasty internal nodejs cache. Could you delete `node_modules` and reinstall?

Comment: @Iyashi Just removed the Ionic project and created it again with no change. Error always exists

Comment: @TarikMokafih import the project into codesandbox because there must be something different in your project is the other project is working fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is a warning/error because you have `<script lang="ts">` if you edit the script tag, it appears to go away in the sample project I created `<script>`